# Upload Image issue in Code Igniter for filenames with whitespace

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, file-upload

I am developing a website using Angular JS + Codeigniter.

The problem lies  with image upload. The file names with space will not be uploaded (eg: "first image.jpg").

If we remove the space then it gets uploaded(eg:"firstimage.jpg"). This is my configuration.

```
$config = array(
  'allowed_types'     => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', 
  'max_size'          => 2048, //2MB max
  'upload_path'       => $this->original_path,
  'remove_spaces'     => true
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: Simply use str_replace to replace all white spaces with another string:

$fileName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove nunecessary white space and symbols from your file name by using.

```
$file_name = $_FILES["userfiles"]['name'];
$newfile_name= preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', "", $file_name);

$config = array('allowed_types'     => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', 
'upload_path'       => $this->original_path,
'file_name'=>$newfile_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd ask "What's wrong with stripping spaces in the way that you have?" Do you really want to keep uploaded files with spaces in them?

The clean way to do this would be to formalise what you have already found and consolidate the logic into a new class or method on some existing (controller?) class:

- Decide what the full range of acceptable characters is for user-uploaded filenames in your app / site.
- Create a regular expression that converts various input strings (e.g. filenames with spaces, tab characters and any other unwanted stuff) into a useable filename according to your requirements
- Call that function / class::function accordingly

Comment: Space is not a problem if the file is uploaded. But file names with space, not get uploaded. If we rename the same file and remove the space, then the file gets uploaded. This is my problem. I want all files to get uploaded irrespect of space..

Answer (score 0):

try this function if only white space issue in your filename:

when you get your data into controller in that function you have to use trim before pass to model like this :

$file_name = trim($_FILES["userfiles"]['name']); so you can easily remove white space from filename.